# Weird behavior when running code with Pool.map() and range() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have come across some strange behavior when using `multiprocessing` and the `range()` generator, and I can't figure out what's going on.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def worker_thread(param):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(param, end=' ', flush=True)

p = Pool(1)
inp = list(range(0, 100))

p.map(worker_thread, inp)
```

When this code is executed (with only 1 thread), the output is as expected:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
```

However, when I raise the thread count to, let's say, 2, the output becomes unexplained:

```
0 13 1 14 2 15 3 16 4 17 ...
```

And so on, and this behavior appears for higher thread counts. Since `list(range(0,100))` generates a list of numbers from 0 to 99 in ascending order, why doesn't `map()` scan the list in the order it's in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the printed items appear in an unexpected order because `multiprocessing.Pool.map` divides the input into chunks that are worked on by each worker process. This [is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) (italics added to emphasise the important bits):

> `map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`
>
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> *This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks.* The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

In the example output you show, it looks like Python has chosen a `chunksize` of 13, since you didn't specify a size of your own. Try passing `1` as the `chunksize` and I think you'll get the output you expected (perhaps at the cost of slower performance, though).

Comment: Correct and well-explained!